# TensorFlow: eval restored graph

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to restore graph from a checkpoint. The checkpoint is created by `tf.Supervisor`. There are both `meta` file and checkpoint.

What I try to achive is to load this graph from separate application to run some operation (i.e. resue existing model).

I do this as the following (as explained here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph):

```
meta = 'path/to/file.meta'

my_graph = tf.Graph()
with my_graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
                saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta)
                saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.dirname(meta)))
                op = my_graph.get_operation_by_name("op")
                print(sess.run(op))
```

What I see is `None`. What I expect to see is 1-D Tensor.
I inspected `my_graph` object using get_collection and find that there are all my variables required for `op` to run correctly initialized with values restored from the checkpoint.
How can I figure out why the operation is not evaluated correctly? I am really stuck here.

The following code:

```
print(sess.run(my_graph.get_operation_by_name("Variable_2")))
print(sess.run(my_graph.get_tensor_by_name("Variable_2:0")))
```

prints

```
None
4818800
```

as if there is no connection between an operation and corresponding variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`tf.Graph.get_operation_by_name()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name) method always returns a [`tf.Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) object. When you pass a `tf.Operation` object to [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run), TensorFlow will execute that operation (and everything on which it depends) and discard its outputs (if any).

If you are interested in the value of a particular output, you have to tell TensorFlow which output (a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor)) you are interested in. There are two main options:

- Get a `tf.Operation` from the graph and then select one of its [`outputs`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#outputs):

  ```
  op = my_graph.get_operation_by_name("op")
  output = op.outputs[0]
  print(sess.run(output))
  ```
- Get a `tf.Tensor` from the graph by calling [`tf.Graph.get_tensor_by_name()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name), and appending `":<output index>"` to the operation's name:

  ```
  output = my_graph.get_tensor_by_name("op:0")
  print(sess.run(output))
  ```

Why does TensorFlow draw this distinction? For one thing, a operation can have multiple outputs, so it is sometimes necessary to be specific about which output you want to fetch. For another, an operation may have a side effect and produce a large output—see [`tf.assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) for an example—and it is often more efficient to pass the `tf.Operation` to `sess.run()` so that the value is not copied back into the Python program.