# Restoring Tensorflow Model but results are incorrect

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am still trying to grasp how to restore a saved tensorflow graph from disk and feed through dictionaries to the model. I have looked at [multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982492/restoring-tensorflow-model) but cannot troubleshoot this. The generic MLP code below (first snippet) saves files to disk, however after restoring (second snippet), my accuracy returns a value of **None**. Any ideas what the reason for this may be?

```
# Import MINST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 256 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

with tf.name_scope('placeholders'):
# tf Graph input
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input],name='x')
    y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes],name='y')

with tf.name_scope('Layer-1'):
    NN_weights_1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1],seed=1),name='NN_weights_1')
    NN_biases_1=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0,shape=[n_hidden_1],name='Const'),name='NN_biases_1')
    func=tf.add(tf.matmul(x, NN_weights_1,name='matmul'), NN_biases_1,name='Addition')
    func_2=tf.nn.relu(func)

with tf.name_scope('Layer-2'):
    NN_weights_2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2],seed=2),name='NN_weights_2')
    NN_biases_2=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0,shape=[n_hidden_2],name='Const'),name='NN_biases_2')
    func_3=tf.add(tf.matmul(func_2, NN_weights_2,name='matmul'), NN_biases_2,name='Addition')
    func_4=tf.nn.relu(func_3)

with tf.name_scope('Output'):
    NN_weights_3=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes],seed=3),name='NN_weights_3')
    NN_biases_3=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0,shape=[n_classes],name='Const'),name='NN_biases_3')
    func_3=tf.add(tf.matmul(func_4, NN_weights_3,name='matmul'), NN_biases_3,name='Addition')
    func_4=tf.nn.sigmoid(func_3)

    # Define loss and optimizer
with tf.name_scope('Operations_'):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=func_4, labels=y),name='cost')
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(func_4, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1),name='correct_prediction')
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"),name='accuracy')
    # Initializing the variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print (("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost="), \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print ("Optimization Finished!")
    print ("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
    saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model',global_step=1000)
```

Restoring Model and passing dictionary for accuracy:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess=tf.Session()    
#First let's load meta graph and restore weights
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,"my_test_model-1000")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
accuracy=graph.get_operation_by_name("Operations_/accuracy")
# Access saved Variables directly
print(sess.run('Layer-1/NN_weights_1:0'))
# This will print 2, which is the value of bias that we saved

print ("Accuracy:", sess.run([accuracy],feed_dict={'placeholders/x:0': mnist.test.images, 'placeholders/y:0': mnist.test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
accuracy=graph.get_operation_by_name("Operations_/accuracy").outputs[0]
```

Tensorflow discards the outputs of Operation objects executed by means of Session.run. See here for detailed explanation: [TensorFlow: eval restored graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595543/tensorflow-eval-restored-graph)

Comment: Genuinely appreciate your answer, and the reference too!