# How to restore saved BiRNN model in tensorflow so that all output neurons correctly bundled to the corresponding output classes

Tags: tensorflow, model, restore

I faced a problem with properly restoring the saved model in tensorflow. I created the Bidirectional RNN model in tensorflow with following code:

```
batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, timesteps, 1],
                                    name="batchX_placeholder")])
batchY_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes],
                                    name="batchY_placeholder")
weights = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(2*STATE_SIZE, num_classes),
                      dtype=tf.float32, name="weights")
biases = tf.Variable(np.zeros((1, num_classes)), dtype=tf.float32,
                     name="biases")
logits = BiRNN(batchX_placeholder, weights, biases)
with tf.name_scope("prediction"):
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
logits=logits, labels=batchY_placeholder))
lr = tf.Variable(learning_rate, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32,
                 name='lr')
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

The architecture of BiRNN created with the following function:

```
def BiRNN(x, weights, biases):
    # Unstack to get a list of 'time_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size,
    # num_input)
    x = tf.unstack(x, time_steps, 1)
    # Forward and Backward direction cells
    lstm_fw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, forget_bias=1.0)
    lstm_bw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(STATE_SIZE, forget_bias=1.0)
    outputs, _, _ = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell,
        lstm_bw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases
```

Then I train a model and save it after each 200 steps:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    current_step = 0
    for batch_x, batch_y in get_minibatch():
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={batchX_placeholder: batch_x,
                                      batchY_placeholder: batch_y})
        current_step += 1
        if current_step % 200 == 0:
            saver.save(sess, os.path.join(model_dir, "model")
```

To run the saved model in inference mode I use saved tensorflow graph in "model.meta" file:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.meta"))
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)
weights = graph.get_tensor_by_name("weights:0")
biases = graph.get_tensor_by_name("biases:0")
batchX_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("batchX_placeholder:0")
batchY_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("batchY_placeholder:0")
logits = BiRNN(batchX_placeholder, weights, biases)
prediction = graph.get_operation_by_name("prediction/Softmax")
argmax_pred = tf.argmax(prediction, 1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
for x_seq, y_gt in get_sequence():
    _, y_pred = sess.run([prediction, argmax_pred],
                    feed_dict={batchX_placeholder: [x_seq]],
                               batchY_placeholder: [[0.0, 0.0]]})
    print("Y ground true: " + str(y_gt) + ", Y pred: " + str(y_pred[0]))
```

And when I run the code in inference mode, I get different results each time I launch it. It seems that output neurons from the softmax layer randomly bundled with different output classes.

So, my question is: How can I save and then correctly restore the model in tensorflow, so that all neurons properly bundled with corresponding output classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, I think that is your problem.

I removed some operations: `logits`, `weights` and `biases` since you don't need them, all those are already loaded, use `graph.get_tensor_by_name` to get them.

For the `prediction`, get the **tensor** instead of the **operation**. (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595543/tensorflow-eval-restored-graph)):

This is the code:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.meta"))
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir))

batchX_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("batchX_placeholder:0")
batchY_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("batchY_placeholder:0")
prediction = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prediction/Softmax:0")
argmax_pred = tf.argmax(prediction, 1)
```

**Edit 1:** I notice that I wasn't clear on why you got different results.

> And when I run the code in inference mode, I get different results
>   each time I launch it.

Notice that although you used the weights from the loaded model, you are creating the `BiRNN` again, and the `BasicLSTMCell` also have weights and other variables that you don't set from your loaded model, hence they need to be initialized (with new random values) resulting in an untrained model again.